# Different values in measuring the elapsed time C++

Tags: c++

I have a simple code and I used clock() and other suggested methods to measure the running time of program. The problem is I got different values when I run it times to times. 
Is there any way to elapsed the real execution time of the program?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doint it uses `#include <ctime>`

```
clock_t t = clock();       //  take a start time 
// ... do something 
clock_t dt = clock() - t;  // take elapsed time 
cout << (((double)dt) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC) * 1000);  // duration in MILLIseconds.
```

The other approach uses the [`high_resolution_clock`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/high_resolution_clock/) of `#include <chrono>`:

```
  chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  //... do something
  chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
  cout << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::duration<double>>(t2 - t).count();
  // or if you prefer duration_cast<milliseconds>(t2 - t).count();
```

In any case, it's normal that you find small variations.  First reason is your other running programms on your PC.  Second reason is the clock accuracy (for example the famous 15 milliseconds on windows).

Comment: Than you, I think the first way you mentioned will produce in millisecond.